# Using apache Shiro with Spring MVC non xml project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I have a project in which i am using Spring mvc 4 and i need to include there apache shiro security. I've tried to search over the web for a solution for my problem but didn't managed to fins something. Although there is a guide at Shiro's web site, but this example is only for xml configured Spring project, and my project doesn't contain any xml at all, and when i am trying to configure Shiro with annotation only it fails.
When i run this project i have an access to all of my end points, and non of them is being restricted by Shiro.
I guess that my configuration is wrong but i am unable to figure out which part of it is wrong.
I am not allowed to use Spring boot (i know that there is examples for that).
here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myproject.menu")
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}

@Bean(name="shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter (){
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/MenuTest/login");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitions("/MenuTest/init=anon");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitions("/MenuTest/**=authc");
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(realm());
    return shiroFilter;
}

private DefaultWebSecurityManager realm(){
    DefaultWebSecurityManager realm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    return realm;
}
}
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 1.4.0 (RC2) release. There is updated Spring and Spring-Boot support.

And examples in the source tree:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/spring-mvc